# Migrate Azure subscription from CSP to EA

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, virtual-network, subscription

I have seen and done Azure subsctiptions migrations from EA to CSP but this time, I need to do the oposite: from CSP to EA. The basics from CSP to EA are documented in the MS site, does anyone done this?

I´m aware of the limitations as per de Microsoft documentation, these are what needs to be moved:

30 VMs (created from de marketplace templates, some with managed disks)
1 Vnet with 2 subnets

Thanks